# Hadoop Basic - error while creating directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have started learning hadoop recently and I am getting the below error while creating new folder -

> vm4learning@vm4learning:~/Installations/hadoop-1.2.1/bin$ ./hadoop fs
>   -mkdir helloworld Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated. 15/06/14 19:46:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS)

Request you to help.below are the namdenode logs -

015-06-14 22:01:08,158 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /home/vm4learning/Installations/hadoop-1.2.1/data/dfs/name does not exist
2015-06-14 22:01:08,161 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/vm4learning/Installations/hadoop-1.2.1/data/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.(FSNamesystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
2015-06-14 22:01:08,182 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/vm4learning/Installations/hadoop-1.2.1/data/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.(FSNamesystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)

2015-06-14 22:01:08,185 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at vm4learning/192.168.1.102
************************************************************/

Comment: mkdir: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: Execute `jps` in console and update your question with that information please.

Comment: JPS gave the below result -8980 Jps
8129 JobTracker
7914 DataNode
8269 TaskTracker
8052 SecondaryNameNode

Comment: Seems that the name node is missing - not sure why - i did format it and then start-all.sh succefully , but while creating a new directory i get the error as shown in my original question.

Comment: Add namenode logs please.

Comment: logs added in the main section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting to create a directory, you should be sure that your hadoop installation is correct, through `jps` command, and looking for any process missing.

In your case, the namenode isn't up.

If you see in the logs, it appears to be that some folders aren't created. Do this:

```
mkdir -p $HADOOP_HOME/dfs/name
mkdir -p $HADOOP_HOME/dfs/name/data
```

And specify in hdfs-site.xml the following.

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
   <value>/usr/local/hadoop/dfs/name/data</value>
   <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
   <value>/usr/local/hadoop/dfs/name</value>
   <final>true</final>
</property>
```

Reinitialize hadoop, and remember to format previous to do anything.

Comment: It worked - thanks a lot - Could you explain me why were these changes required and what exactly happened - thanks again

Comment: Your HDFS folders are created on top of your FS. That's why, when i see that your namenode was complaining about those inexistent FS directories (the default ones used to create the hadoop filesystem) i suppose that you didn't create them yet. I tell you to specify those properties in hdfs-site because if you don't do that, it could lead to another problems too. Np

Comment: Hope that's enough for you. And maybe you could accept my answer for this question if you have some time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why the same error may appear is that you still not executed the formatting of the namenode like that:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

I have missed the step 7 from this tutorial (https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/377/latest-hadoop-321-installation-on-windows-10-step-by-step-guide ) and faced the same error

`hdfs` is the utility from `HADOOP_HOME/bin`